# How to prevent horizontal scrolling when carrying out a text search?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I open a particular CSS file, then immediately search for some text, VSCode will scroll vertically to the line of the first match, as expected.  But in addition, VSCode will also scroll horizontally to the right.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXF5X.jpg) are before and after screenshots illustrating this jump.  This forces me to re-scroll to the left.  Is there a way to prevent this horizontal jump from occurring?

In this particular search, the first match occurs at column 41 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN51v.jpg)), so I'm not sure why VSCode is making this horizontal jump.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio has the same behavior, which I also find annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can press `alt+z` to wrap your lines and this way, when you search, it won't scroll to the left.

***===UPDATE===***

I have found a way to wrap every file in your project so it won't overflow outside of your viewport. Simply go to `settings, text editor, scroll down to word wrap and select on from dropdown`

Comment: OK.  When I press `alt+z`, it seems to wrap all lines on the screen--not all lines in the document.  Is that correct? If so, how do I do the latter, or ensure that all lines in the document are already wrapped when I open the file?

Comment: Okay, I have added an update to answer which might be more helpful.

Comment: I haven't tested your update, but I'll just mark it as the answer if you're OK with that.